# Why does this not swap a and b?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, swap, function-definition

I'm very new to C and just starting to learn pointers. I'm very confused by this piece of code in lecture. I'm wondering if anyone can explain it to help me understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *p1, int *p2) 
{      int *p;
       p = p1; p1 = p2; p2 = p;
}
void main() 
{      int a, b;
       int *pointer_1, *pointer_2;
       scanf("%d, %d", &a, &b);
       pointer_1 = &a; pointer_2 = &b;
       if (a < b) swap(pointer_1, pointer_2);
       printf("\n%d > %d\n", *pointer_1, *pointer_2);
}
```

The problem is why this doesn't swap `a` and `b`?

Comment: Gentle introduction [here](https://dev.to/erikwhiting88/c-pointers-101-part-1-a-gentle-introduction-3an6) that you might find helpful.

Comment: Because function parameters are passed by copy and that's valid for pointers. Those of the main function remain unchanged even after calling the swap function.

Comment: Did you google "c swap" to see in what way your code differs from the common implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
 p = p1; p1 = p2; p2 = p;
```

you're swapping the addresses (the change is local to the function scope). You need to swap the values (`*p1`, `*p2`) stored in those memory locations.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
void swap(int *p1, int *p2) 
{      int *p;
       p = p1; p1 = p2; p2 = p;
}
```

actually swaps nothing. The pointers are passed to the function by value

```
if (a < b) swap(pointer_1, pointer_2);
```

That is the function deals with its own local variables `p1` and `p2` that were initialized by copies of values of the original pointers used as argument expressions. Within the function these local variables are indeed swapped but the original pointers used as argument expressions stay unchanged.

You need to swap objects of the type `int` passed to the function `swap` by reference that is through pointers to them. That is you need to change values of the variables `a` and `b` defined in main.

So the function should look the following way

```
void swap(int *p1, int *p2) 
{      int x;
       x = *p1; *p1 = *p2; *p2 = x;
}
```

Dereferencing the pointers you get a direct access to the pointed variables `a` and `b` and can exchange their values.

If you want to exchange values of the pointers `pointer_1` and `pointer_2` themselves then the function can look the following way

```
void swap(int **p1, int **p2) 
{      int *p;
       p = *p1; *p1 = *p2; *p2 = p;
}
```

and the function will be called like

```
if (a < b) swap( &pointer_1, &pointer_2);
```

That is again the arguments must be passed by reference through pointers to them. In this case the values of the variables `a` and `b` will not be changed but values of the pointers will be changed.

Try yourself the both approaches and compare their results. Output in `main` the variables `a` and `b` and the values of the dereferenced pointers as for example

```
printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b );
printf("*pointer_1 = %d, *pointer_2 = %d\n", *pointer_1, *pointer_2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap(int *p1, int *p2) 
{      
    int *p;
    p = p1; p1 = p2; p2 = p;
}
```

Your function, swap, does not actually modify the values of p1 and p2
You can fix it by replacing `p = p1; p1 = p2; p2 = p;` with this

```
void swap(int *p1, int *p2) 
{      
    int p;
    p = *p1; *p1 = *p2; *p2 = p;
}
```

In this case, we modify the value of what the pointer is pointing to.